# How do I keep wrapping lines intelligently in Vim, without having to use 'gqG'?

Tags: vim

I'm a journalist and novice programmer, and would like to use Vim more for my daily writing. But my problem is that Vim doesn't seem to keep lines wrapped consistently. What I mean by that is, even if my line wraps at 80 as desired while I'm writing, if I go back and edit a line (say, by adding or deleting text), Vim does not keep the line wrapped. It looks like I can fix this manually afterward using `gqG`; but that's a little annoying to keep having to do, and sometimes it results in oddly broken lines.

Here's what I'm using in my `.vimrc` file for word processing in Vim.

```
" Enable word processing
func! WordProcessorMode()
    setlocal textwidth=80
    setlocal smartindent
    setlocal noexpandtab
    setlocal wrap 
endfu
com! WP call WordProcessorMode()
```

After calling `WP`, here's my situation:

Two separate paragraphs, entered with clean wrapping:

[Image: Vim window with two separate paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq0hM.png)

But when I try to combine them, this is what happens:

[Image: Paras combined, but text runs long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERMtw.png)

As stated above, if I enter `gqG` that tends to clean it up and wrap back at column 80 as desired. But depending on how I have edited the other lines, they may then be broken at odd places (i.e. well before 80).

Is there a way to keep lines wrapped intelligently and consistently at a set `textwidth`? I've searched for an answer to this but not found one. Setting `linebreak` and `nolist` doesn't seem to have any effect. `formatoptions` is set to `tcq`.

Thanks!

Comment: The `a`  format option may help. So try `:set formatoptions+=a` then start typing text in INSERT mode.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Thanks very much @Sergio!

Comment: `textwidth` set to a non-zero value hardwraps lines by inserting an end of line character. As an alternative, consider softwrapping instead. Do `:set textwidth=0` to disable hardwrapping and do `:set wrap`. With this, long lines will wrap when they reach the edge of the window or terminal. You might want to resize your terminal or window to 80 characters wide.

Answer (score 1):

This is called *automatic formatting*, and enabled via the `a` flag in `'formatoptions'`. From [`:help fo-table`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table):

> **a** Automatic formatting of paragraphs.  Every time text is inserted or
>     deleted the paragraph will be reformatted.  See |auto-format|.
>     When the 'c' flag is present this only happens for recognized
>     comments.

The crucial thing here is to properly tell Vim what comprises a *paragraph*. See [`:help auto-format`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#auto-format) for details. Else, you'll soon end up with one large block of text, without any breaks in it! This can work well with pure text, but I personally find it irritating.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gq` in the visual mode after you edited a line? i.e. select the paragraph you had one line edited using `vip` and type `gq` that shall reformat the paragraph within which a line has been edited.